# How to add touch-enabled lightbox features to [react-slick]?

Tags: reactjs, react-slick

I've recently moved to React after building sites which used jQuery plugins to provide most functionality. To create an image slider + lightbox, I used to combine [slick.js](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) with [halkaBox.js](https://ahmednooor.github.io/halkaBox.js/) or [SimpleLightbox](http://simplelightbox.com) (which was pretty easy).

Now that I'm using React, I've found [react-slick](https://github.com/akiran/react-slick) to be a great slider component, but I'm not sure how best to add touch-enabled lightbox functionality to it. Is there a touch-enabled React lightbox component that pairs well with react-slick? Is there a proper way incorporate a JS plugin like [halkaBox.js](https://ahmednooor.github.io/halkaBox.js/) with a React component like react-slick?

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: i'v just checked click-react demo page - and it can swipe it by finger. Could you explain what `touch-enabled lightbox ` stands for?

Comment: Yeah, the react-slick slider is touch-enabled, which is great (not sure what click-react is...). A lightbox means the ability to tap on an image and have it pop open a fullscreen image slider. See the halkaBox and SimpleLightbox links for examples of what I mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, you can use react-slick + react-image-lightbox. Local state is a good place to save path of the current image;

```
import Slider from 'react-slick';
import Lightbox from 'react-image-lightbox';

class Slider extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      images: ['src/image1.png', 'src/image2.png', 'src/image3.png'],
      current: ''
    }
  }

  getSliderSettings(){
   return {
      dots: true,
      infinite: true,
      speed: 500,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1
   }
  }

  handleClickImage = (e, image) => {
   e && e.preventDefault();

   this.setState({
     current: image
   })
  }

  handleCloseModal = (e) => {
   e && e.preventDefault();

   this.setState({
     current: ''
   })
  }

  render(){
   const settings = this.getSliderSettings();
   const { images, current } = this.state;

   return (
     <div>
      <Slider {...settings}>
        { images.map(image => (
           <img src={image} onClick={ e => this.handleClickImage(e, image)}  />

        ))} 
      </Slider>

      {current &&
         <Lightbox
            mainSrc={current}
            onCloseRequest={this.handleCloseModal}
            />
      }
    </div>
   )
  }
}
```

Comment: This is clever! Thanks so much for this solution. Just one thing: in order to work, <img src="image"... /> needs to be rewritten as <img src={image} ... />.